# Why doesn't my manifest.json trigger the "Install Web App" modal?

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps, netlify

here's the manifest: https://twoshot.app/manifest.json

```json
{
  "short_name": "TwoShot",
  "name": "TwoShot",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "logo.svg",
      "type": "image/svg"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/explore",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ea0417",
  "background_color": "#1c1c1c",
  "scope": "/",
  "orientation": "landscape-primary"
}
```

When I open https://twoshot.app, no installation options show up

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar JSON on my website, and I can see the installation option popping up. You didn't define a `description` key in your JSON. Can you try to add one and see what happens?

Comment: That didn't fix it

Comment: indeed, the description is not mandatory. my next question would be if you are also providing a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Guides/Making_PWAs_installable#service_worker). It's the only think I can think of that would cause this to happen

Comment: I'll look into adding a web worker - i think thats the issue